# asp.NET - Problems with Static Selected Style for a Selected Page on the menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I am using asp.NET 4.0 with C# and have recently created a custom design for my local web application. I would like that when a page is selected, it has a different background colour (usually in plain html + css we just set a menu item as active). I tried using  but it is not working, it stays the same colour as the others. Does any one has any experience with this?

Code in Site Master:

```
            <h2>Dashboard</h2>
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Vertical" >
                <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="selectedMenu" /> 
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="View Submissions"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Imports.aspx" Text="Import"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Submission.aspx" Text="Insert Submission"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Reports.aspx" Text="Reports"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/CurrencyMaintenance.aspx" Text="Currency Maintenance" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Remittance.aspx" Text="Remittance" />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

CSS:

```
/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #FFF; /*680840*/
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    height: 20px;
    width: 175px;
    color: #000; /*FFF*/
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #680840;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.selectedMenu
{
    background-color: #680840 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #680840;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is what it looks like on Hover, I would like a similar effect on selected.

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the .NET menu. There is some information regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655377/how-to-style-an-asp-net-menu-with-css). What you might want to do then is remove the staticSelectedStyle attribute and simply add this to your css:

```
.menu a.static.selected
{
    background-color: #680840 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

You might also have to add some code to your master's page load to determine which should be the selected item like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
    foreach (MenuItem item in NavigationMenu.Items)
    {
        item.Selected = item.NavigateUrl.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that fixed it, I've been trying to fix this a while, you were spot on :)

Comment: Nice, but fails when path is "~/xyz.aspx". This works better: item.Selected = item.NavigateUrl.Equals(Right(path, item.NavigateUrl.Length), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: smirkingman's solutions uses method Right() which is a VB function. Not very nice to use in C#, instead use function SubString().